# IndexError: list assignment index out of range in python 2.7.11

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I was just solving a problem using python, and my codes are:

```
from math import sin,pi
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pylab
N=20
x = np.linspace(0,1, N)
def v(x):
    return 100*sin(pi*x)

#set up initial condition
u0 = [0.0]              # Boundary conditions at t= 0
for i in range(1,N):
    u0[i] = v(x[i])
```

And I would want to plot the results by updating v(x) in `range(0, N)` after. it looks simple but perhaps you guys could help since it gives me an error, like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/universe/Desktop/Python/sample.py", line 13, in <module>
    u0[i] = v(x[i])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u` is a list with one element, so you can't assign values to indices that don't exist. Instead make `u` a dictionary

```
u = {}
u[0] = 0.0
for i in range(1,N):
    u[i] = v(x[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `u0[i] = v(x[i])` to `u0.append(v(x[i]))`. But you should write more elegantly as

```
u0 = [v(xi) for xi in x]
```

Indices `i` are bug magnets.

Comment: Thanks very big guys as all the codes here are all working

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using numpy, I'd suggest using [np.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). That way you can pass the array `x` directly to the function and the function will return an array of the same size with the function applied on each element of the input array.

```
from math import sin,pi
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pylab
N=20
x = np.linspace(0,1, N)
def v(x):
    return 100*sin(pi*x)

vectorized_v = np.vectorize(v) #so that the function takes an array of x's and returns an array again
u0 = vectorized_v(x)
```

Out:

```
array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.64594590e+01,   3.24699469e+01,
         4.75947393e+01,   6.14212713e+01,   7.35723911e+01,
         8.37166478e+01,   9.15773327e+01,   9.69400266e+01,
         9.96584493e+01,   9.96584493e+01,   9.69400266e+01,
         9.15773327e+01,   8.37166478e+01,   7.35723911e+01,
         6.14212713e+01,   4.75947393e+01,   3.24699469e+01,
         1.64594590e+01,   1.22464680e-14])
```